# How can I get the current time in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm looking for the equivalent of MySQL now().  Any format is fine.

Comment: Hint:  `getdate()`, `current_timestamp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a User Defined Function (UDF) like this.

```
function now() {
    return new Date();
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
SELECT udf.now(), c.date, c.id FROM c WHERE c.date < udf.now()
```

Comment: your answer worked perfectly. 
Maybe you should explain the UDF in a little bit more details. 
I am very new to Azure Cosmos and did not get the first sentence at once.
"You should create an User Defined Function like this"
Was more appropriate for a begniner like me.
Just a hint ...

Answer (score 5):

As of the end of 2020, there are 2 functions to get current date/time in Cosmos DB:

```sql
SELECT 
    GetCurrentDateTime() AS utc_datetime_iso_8601,
    GetCurrentTimestamp() AS timestamp_with_milliseconds
```

returns

```json
[
    {
        "utc_datetime_iso_8601": "2020-12-25T22:56:27.3453234Z",
        "timestamp_with_milliseconds": 1608936987345
    }
]
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-date-time-functions#functions-to-obtain-the-date-and-time)